# Как в VirtualBox сделать boot c usb флешки?

Tags: virtualbox, boot, live-usb

Я добавляю фильтр флешки VirtualBox и она исчезает из Win7 и читается в Ubuntu в VirtualBox, но в (<kbd>F12</kbd>) вариантах boot флешки нет.

Comment: В Virtual Box не работает загрузка с ЮСБ устройств. Устройство передается в гостевую систему (которая внутри VB) и правильно работает, а вот грузиться не будет. В отличие от CD

Comment: А есть эмуляторы host win 7 32 bit guest Ubuntu 32 bit которые поддерживают boot с usb и желательно прямой доступ например к плате wi fi (а не эмуляцию шнурового соединения)?

Comment: насчет платы wi-fi: NAT через нее. Т.е. на компе оставляем единственную рабочую плату (wi-fi), в настройках VB NAT-ируем сетевое соединение гостевой ОС через хостовую (материнскую)

Comment: [Вот][1] хорошее руководство [1]: http://windowsnotes.ru/programs/zagruzka-c-usb-v-oracle-virtualbox/

Comment: Спасибо грамадное весь инет перекопал был ответ - категорически невозможно. Плюнул и теперь загружаюсь с флешки через комп а вот оно!!:):) Спасибо

Comment: Великолепно! не знал о такой возможности. Пусть и через танцы с бубуном - но главное, что можно сделать!